# React-Native Native CLI Typescript Project is working properly but showing return area in class component as errors

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

Showing the below error message on all components, react-native init created a functional component template and showing errors that happen after converted to class components.

> JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.ts(2607)
> 'View' cannot be used as a JSX component.
> Its instance type 'View' is not a valid JSX element.
> Type 'View' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 2 more.ts(2786)

Can anyone help with this problem?
[image]

Comment: How did you type this class?

Comment: I type this using an expo typescript project and put it in the react-native project.

Comment: Make sure you are extending React.Component

Comment: Yes, Iike bellow,
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class GooglePlacesInput extends Component {}